# Integrate chatbot into any third-party messaging API

Tags: api, chat, messaging, chatbot, messenger

I want to make a unified "inbox" for messages from across multiple platforms, some of them are widely supported by all mejor chatbot services, like Facebook Messenger, others are more obscure like WhatsApp, but others are plain unsupported (like Steam Web Chat).

I've encountered several solutions that have some sort of "one-click" integration for the most popular messengers, but I can't find one that will let you integrate third-party messengers (which ideally have an API to read/send messages at the very least) into a chatbot-like service. Is there such a thing out there?

PS: I don't really care about fancy AI conversational support, I'd just like to receive all messages into, say, one webhook I can then act on, and also be able to reply to them.

Comment: Not really sure what are you looking for, is it a service like api.ai or wit.ai which aggregates more messaging clients? do you need "one click" integration or is it ok to do some rest api consuming ?

Comment: I think I'm repeating myself here but let's try different words: I want to be able to consume messages that come through different sources (Facebook Messenger, WhatsApp, etc) and act on them (reply, trigger other actions) without having to subscribe to multiple "chatbot services" and rewrite the same code. But most importantly, I need to be able to integrate other messaging services by providing the corresponding API/REST endpoints. One-click integration would be nice but not needed if I can hook them up myself. I'm starting to think there's actually a vacant for said service.

Comment: So essentially something like api.ai but allowing me to specify certain API endpoints to pool for messages (or webhooks to receive them, or whatever), get them into their system and reply to them.

Comment: On a side note, have you been able to integrate with WhatsApp- you're right that solutions seem quite obscure? Is this the API you have used? https://market.mashape.com/datayuge/whatsapp

Answer (score 2):

API.ai doesn't have an 'integration pooling' architecture, it treats each platform as a separate integration or conversation. Given that, you'll have to build your own server side message pooling solution which plugs into all your 3rd party APIs, and then pools/queues messages across all streams before passing to API.ai, and with some messageID/tracking system on your server side solution to remember which 3rd party API to respond to with API.ai response. Something like this as an aggregate/pooling function should work:

```js
var queue = [];
var queueProcessing = false;

function queueRequest(request) {
    queue.push(request);
    if (queueProcessing) {
        return;
    }
    queueProcessing = true;
    processQueue();
}

function processQueue() {
    if (queue.length == 0) {
        queueProcessing = false;
        return;
    }
    var currentRequest = queue.shift();
    //Send to API.ai
    request(currentRequest, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error || response.body.error) {
            console.log("Error sending messages!");
        }
        processQueue();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is have a Node.js backend.
Direct every messaging integration to it and then direct that to API.AI.

So the flow would be like this:

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the advice but I'm trying to avoid writing the whole integration myself, ideally api.ai could provide some sort of plugin functionality so developers wouldn't have to repeat the process over and over for the same messaging platforms, and could discover the ones already integrated by the community. But I know this would be best suited as a feature suggestion for them.

Comment: I agree with you but from my own experience the 1 click integrations in api ai are shallow and limit you quit a bit. If you would like to do any manipulation before it get to api ai then you will need a backend any way

Answer (score 0):

There is a service called [Message.io](http://message.io/home) which does I believe what you want. They support the widest range of platforms.

Message.io sits between your bot and the messaging platforms, you receive messages in a standardized way from Message.io, and when sending messages out to users, it converts it to the appropriate format for the platform you're responding to.